# which WindowBuilder Swing widget should I use to make a System.out "console" display?

Tags: java, linux, swing

I do not want to give up visibility to all the data the program prints to System.out as I upgrade a linux console app to a Swing app.  If I dump it to a file, I might never see something important.

Which WindowBuilder Swing widget should I use to make a System.out "console" display?

(I am using Java, Eclipse, ubuntu, Swing and WindowBuilder.)

**Edit: I used jfpoilpret's suggestion and Mohaimin's suggestion.** The result is a private static reference to a JTextArea (inside a scrollable pane inside a WindowBuilder structure).  Then I use a getter method to expose the JTextArea and I invoke the getter as follows:

`public static PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new mySwingConsole(getter()))`

where mySwingConsole is a Writer.

Comment: Don't know WindowBuilder, but I guess there's no ready-to-use "console" widget. Normally you'll use a `JTextArea` and you'll have to replace `System.out` to your own `OutputStream` that will then append every text, written to your stream, to the text area.

Comment: Methinks that that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: FYI: I see that WindowBuilder for Swing offers a JTextArea.

Comment: While you're upgrading, upgrade the app. to use logging over `System.err` or `System.out`.

Comment: In most cases, I'd rather use a JScrollPane "console" that colors my errors and warnings all in context with my miscellaneous output than to use a logging viewer.  Context is really important.  Perhaps there are viewers that do not clutter with timestamps and severe/info/warning but I cannot imagine anything more terse than console output that I am completely in control of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is described in the "edit" to the question.  I used jfpoilpret's suggestion and Mohaimin's suggestion.  If jfpoilpret wants to repost his comment as an answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 3):

You might use a class such as the [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) for the `System.err`/`System.out` side of it.

[image: Message Console]